# Changing the Size of my ListView by one Pixel messes up Formatting

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-relativelayout

Let me show you two links to demonstrate my point:

http://i.snag.gy/QP1i2.jpg (The ListView is 60 pixels)
http://i.snag.gy/DvXsL.jpg (The ListView is 61 pixels)

The whole file is done with an outer Vertical LinearLayout to provide weighted percentages (e.g. the ListView is 75%, the search part is 4%, so on and so forth) independent of device screen size. Within that outer LinearLayout I have a nested Layout (Linear or Relative) depending on my needs for the particular row.

It works beautifully, except for the last part. And it seems a lot of the items I try adding end up messing the formatting so I'm not sure if the problem is how I'm doing the ListView. Anyways, here's the relevant code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:paddingLeft="0dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/searchdivider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:src="@drawable/searchdivider" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchdivider" >
    </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I should add that I don't want the height to be 60dp, obviously. I want it to fill_parent; however I picked the arbitrary value of 60 and 61 to figure out exactly what change makes the layout mess up.

2nd EDIT: I think I figured out the problem. It seems when I make the Theme AppCompat, it looks and acts fine. But when I make the Theme NoTitleBar (with or without fullscreen) then it acts all screwy. I haven't changed it in the manifest but rather the place in the graphical layout that lets you modify it for that one activity only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I presume that you are using a linear layout vertical/?

Comment: EDIT: Yes I am. (Note I originally said this was resolved, but it turns out it only acts screwy when I make the Theme the noTitleBar one. If the TitleBar is there it seems to work fine. Any suggestions?)

Comment: then instead of creating your own action bar.. you could actually costumized the action without using the noTitleBar

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. I don't believe I ever am creating an action bar (I assume you mean in the java files?). My thought is to see what happens if I programmatically disable the title bar but I'm still trying to figure that bit out

Answer (score 0):

android:gravity="left" on imageView and android:gravity="right" on the other listView

Comment: Does that mean I should use a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout?

Comment: you can use both, preferrend relative because it have auto gravity inherited **you can use both**

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it doesn't look to me like it's solved the problem.